# Export MongoDB to Relational database

Tags: sql, mongodb

I'm trying to export my mongodb database to a relational database, I've found a few expensive tools but nothing open source so far. 
Do you know any blog post/open source project to do that?
If there is not such a thing, how do I start to build my own mapper from mongo to sql?

Answer (score 0):

If your mongodb database is not too complex, I think you can just start to build your own mapper. Actually, if you have specific needs, it's better to code your own mapper because it will correspond to your expectation.